# How to use Scala class from Java that is in a different package?

Tags: java, scala

When trying to import a class that is in a different package, I am getting a the type cannot be resolved

Comment: Can you post some code showing the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

src/foo/Foo.scala:

```
package foo

object Foo {
  def fooStatic { println("object Foo::fooStatic") }
}

class Foo(n: Int) {
  def foo { println("class Foo::foo # " + n) }
}
```

src/bar/Bar.java:

```
package bar;
import foo.Foo;

public class Bar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo1 = new Foo(1);
        Foo foo2 = new Foo(2);

        // prints "class Foo::foo # 1"
        foo1.foo();
        // prints "class Foo::foo # 2"
        foo2.foo();
        // prints "object Foo::fooStatic"
        Foo.fooStatic();
    }
}
```

**Class** methods could be accessed in a *normal* way and **object** methods like *static* class members.

Comment: I thought so and it works in one of my projects. There seems to be something broken with Scala IDE or the pom configuration.

Comment: @dlots: Maven (POM) I havn't used yet. Which version of Eclipse do you use? I use Indigo (Eclipse 3.7) together with Scala 2.9.final and am very happy.

Comment: The problem was that I added the webapp directory as a source directory in Eclipse. This probably caused a xml interpretation error and caused Eclipse to error on these imports. Removing the webapp directory fixed the problem.